# OpenID in a Win8 Metro-style app (Authenticating with Steam)

Tags: c#, .net, openid, windows-runtime

I've been thinking of making a Windows 8 Metro (WinRT) style application that would allow the user to login/authenticate with the Steam WebAPI so I could use their stats etc that they provide. However I'm not sure how to approach this.

Almost every answer to authenticating against an OpenID provider says to use [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) but when installing this with NuGet it fails saying that a dependency (CodeContracts.Unofficial 1.002) doesn't have any assemblies compatible with my project's target (.NET framework 4.5) so I'm guessing that either hasn't been updated yet for Windows 8 apps or won't be due to some WinRT restriction.

I've also looked in to using the .NET library's [WebAuthenticationBroker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx) class, but I'm not sure how to use this with an OpenID provider. The samples for it seem to only be for OAuth, and on the [Steam WebAPI Page](http://steamcommunity.com/dev) the only information provided is:

> Just download an OpenID library for your language and platform of choice and use http://steamcommunity.com/openid as the provider. The returned Claimed ID will contain the user's 64-bit SteamID.

I tried simply using the given URL by passing it straight to `AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions, Uri);` but this just gives a white screen with a spinner on it.

Does anyone have any advice for me on how to either get an OpenID library working with a metro application, or how to use the WebAuthenticationBroker to auth via the OpenID protocol (preferably against steam specifically)?

Answer (score 1):

http://steamcommunity.com/dev This say you have to use OpenID but it seem the C# lib for openID do not work with .Net 4.5.

You might could make an C++ dll window store app project and use the OpenID C++ to do the job. Than add that dll to your C# window store app.